# The website I am working on is not responsive in chrome debugger(and my android phone) but works fine in firefox debugger. I need help fixing it

Tags: html, css

This is how the page looks in chrome

[image: This is how the page looks in chrome]

and

This is how the page looks in Firefox

[image: This is how the page looks in Firefox]

The website I am working on is not responsive in chrome debugger(and my android phone) but works fine in firefox debugger. I need help fixing it.

and I also need help in turning five buttons into radio. and translate button to be a toggle button.

the code I have used is as follows.

```css
.NoDisplay {
  display: none;
}


.Qustion {
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-header {
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50%;
}

.instructionsContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress {
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.QustionHeading {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  ;
}

.InstructionsHeading {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.instructionText {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 410;
}

.QustionText {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.optionsContainer {
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.OptionsBtn {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.OptionsBtn::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.card-footer {
  text-align: none;
}

.TranslateBtn {
  margin-left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.TranslateBtn:checked {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.NextBtn {
  margin-right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

. @media (max-width: 768px) {
  .optionsContainer {
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .OptionsBtn {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test page</title>

  <title>TP Portal -- Jokes</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>



  <!-- <div class="loader-wrapper screen1" id="loadImg">
    <img src="V-ReapLogoAnimation.svg" class="loaderImage" alt="loeading" />
  </div>
  <div class=" section-left " id="leftOverlay"></div>
  <div class=" section-right " id="rightOverlay"></div> -->

  <div class="Container-main">



    <div class="screen3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
          <div class="card text-center Qustion Qustion1">
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="ProgressBar">
                <h2 class="QustionHeading">Qustion No 5</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="70" style="width:50%">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- <hr />
              <div class="instructions">
                <h2 class="InstructionsHeading">==> Instructions <== </h2>
                <p class="instructionText">
                  Select one of the options below to indicate how well the statement describes you
                </p>
              </div> -->

            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="QustionText">I look for things that need to be done.</h2>
              <div class="optionsContainer">
                <button class="btn OptionsBtn" type="radio" name="qustion1" value="5">vary well</button>
                <br />
                <button class="btn OptionsBtn" type="radio" name="qustion1" value="4">vary well</button>
                <br />
                <button class="btn OptionsBtn" type="radio" name="qustion1" value="3">vary well</button>
                <br />
                <button class="btn OptionsBtn" type="radio" name="qustion1" value="2">vary well</button>
                <br />
                <button class="btn OptionsBtn" type="radio" name="qustion1" value="1">vary well</button>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <button class="btn TranslateBtn" id="TranslateBtn1">Translate</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <button class="btn NextBtn">Next</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>







    <div class="footer">
    </div>


  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I found the answer on Reddit. I had to add the line "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">" to the header of my html file.

Comment: You should comment in below and mark accepted answers for everyone know that instead of comment in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on Reddit. I had to add the line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to the header of my HTML file